# Format byebug's output

Tags: ruby, byebug

I've recently done a fresh install of my system and I'm seeing some odd behaviour from `byebug`. For instance, arrays are listed on element on line instead of having everything on the same line. Here is an example:

```
(byebug) [1,2,3]
1
2
3
```

Normally, I would expect:

```
(byebug) [1,2,3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

How can I get `byebug` to display arrays "normally"?

Comment: Pretty sure it's a new behavior from the current version. I noted this behavior as well when I upgraded my setup. Try `[1,2,3].to_s ` and it should print what you expect.

Comment: While your workaround works, I would like to have the old behaviour back, I don't want to write that extra `to_s` on each call...

Comment: Why ask here? Doesn't it make more sense to ask the author and maintainers who would have implemented the behavior?

Comment: As a workaround you may use `pry` and `pry-byebug` respectively.

Comment: I've asked here since I wasn't sure that this changed in a recent version of `byebug`.

Comment: I can also confirm this upon upgrading to byebug 6...the behavior is particularly difficult when the array is very long.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed with the latest versions of `byebug`: `gem 'byebug', '~> 8.0'`. Arrays are properly printed now.